# What does up to order isomorphism mean?

Tags: real-analysis

In my real analysis course, we defined the $\mathbb{R}$ to be: "the unique ordered field, up to order isomorphism, that satisfies the least upper bound property."
My question is, what does up to order isomorphism mean in this sense?

Comment: A bijectine map $f$ such that $x \leq y$ iff $f(y) \leq f(y)$.

Comment: It means that an ordered field has the least upper bound property if and only if it is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb R$, i.e., if and only if there is an order-preserving bijection between it and $\Bbb R$.